# Resharper like syntax highlighting

Tags: c#, resharper

I've used resharper for a while now and i notice that it sometimes adds advise to your code such as this:

[image]

I'm writing a visual studio add-in where i'd like to do the same thing.
Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You can extend Resharper with new rules and plugin. Will that make sense in you situation?

Comment: Where would i be getting the dll for Resharper? I only know i've installed it allready into visual studio as a plugin.

I've found Resharper PowerToys, but once i open it in Visual Studio (as a solution file), im missing the JetBrains namespace.

Comment: Not to be extremely dismissive but if the recommendation made by @asgerhallas isn't suitable, I would seriously recommend reconsidering your thoughts on this unless you have a full team to dedicate to this project. Source code analysis that R# does is incredibly complex and has taken them YEARS to make it work very well and very performant. Even after the years of product development they still frequently face many builds that results in extreme performance issues or memory leaks. A project like this isn't something possible by one person.

Comment: I wouldn't be that crazy to take on such a project by myself. I'm just trying to find something i can work with and extend, not create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hadi Hariri has written some good introductions to extend Resharper either with plugins:

http://hadihariri.com/2010/01/12/writing-plug-ins-for-resharper-part-1-of-undefined/

http://hadihariri.com/2010/07/20/writing-plug-ins-for-resharper-part-2-of-n/

... or with a new custom pattern matching feature in Resharper 5.

http://hadihariri.com/2010/08/19/highlighting-custom-patterns-with-resharper/

For getting started with writing the plugin Hadi describes, reference the following dll's from the Resharper install directory:

[image: references for creating the plugin]

And for getting further checkout the source Resharper PowerToys:

http://resharperpowertoys.codeplex.com/

Mind that there are some differences in how to implement the plugins between Resharper versions.